# Current Logged in user Timezone

Tags: apex, datetime

How do you get the current logged-in user's DateTime in apex? Is it Datetime.now() or system.now() ?

Comment: Both methods do exactly the same thing. All Datetime values are stored internally in UTC ("GMT" as Salesforce call it) but are automatically converted to the viewing user's time zone in the Salesforce UI when using standard rendering/components.

Answer (score 1):

They both return the time in GMT. You will have to use the format() function to get the date in current user's timezone.

See : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_format

Comment: It rather depends on what you are doing with the value; You don't have to format the value if you assign it to a Datetime field, for example. All Datetime values are stored internally as "GMT" (UTC) but are presented in the current user's timezone automatically when using standard field presentation. Basically Salesforce UI automatically handles the time zone conversion between UTC and the user's time zone for I/O.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: TimeZone tz = UserInfo.getTimeZone();

Or if you want from a specific region: TimeZone roTZ = Timezone.getTimeZone('Europe/Bucharest');

Comment: I've downvoted because this doesn't answer the question being asked (though to be fair, OP's title and question body are different from one another).